# What does this Regex replace?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to mention that I still don't understand how regexs work. Please have a look at the below code.

```
titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", " ");
```

Here, `titleAndBodyContainer` is a `String`. But, what does it replace with a space? Full stop? Comma? Question mark?

Comment: The Regex Coach has a pretty good mechanism for explaining regular Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

It replaces a dot followed by either whitespace or the end of the input with a space.

```
| dot (double-escaped)
|  | look ahead non-capturing group
|  |  | whitespace (double-escaped)
|  |  |  | or
|  |  |  || end of input ("$")
\\.(?=\\s|$)
```

Check the API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg).

Comment: My goodnes, doe that mean it do not replace ", ?, /, (, ), - etc?

Comment: @GloryOfSuccess well nope.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Image from: **Regexper.com** `http://www.regexper.com/#\.%28%3F%3D\s|%24%29`

Example:

```
System.out.println("Hello. ".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
System.out.println("Hello.".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
System.out.println(".".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
System.out.println(". ".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
System.out.println(".com".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
System.out.println(". Hi".replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", "_"));
```

Output is:

```
Hello_ //there is a space after Hello_
Hello_//no space this time
_
_ //again, space after _
.com
_ Hi
```

The important thing is that the white space or end of line characters are not consumed. They are only used to check for a match, but not replaced. Thats why in the first example, `"Hello. "` results in `"Hello_ "` and not just `"Hello_"`

Answer (score 0):

In your code it is replacing all the dots(`.`) with space(). But with a condition. The dots must have to be before a white space or at the end of the line.

For example:

```
alex is dead. and alive.dead   
alex is dead.
```

In above two examples it will only replace the dots after the `dead` as it has space or end of line.

Answer (score 0):

It replaces dots followed by a whitespace character  `\t\n\x0B\f\r` or `end of line` or `end of input` with space

Answer (score 0):

```
titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)", " ");
```

This matches a dot (`.`) followed by a space or the end of string, and replaces it with a space.

If you want to replace `?/()` as well, you could try something like :

```
titleAndBodyContainer = titleAndBodyContainer.replaceAll("[\\.\\?\\/\\(\\)](?=\\s|$)", " ");
```